# Snap.svg polygon animation and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, snap.svg

I'm running on a bug which seem to appear only in IE

when I try to do an animation of a polygon with Snap.svg I got this message

> SVG4602: SVG Point list has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed.

here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/fRphm/4/

```js
var SvgInit = (function() {

  function SvgInit(elem) {

    this.elem = elem;
    this.inAnim = false;
    this.animTime = 500;

    this.panel02Svg;

    this.init();

  }

  /*******************************************
   *
   *    init the Svg
   *
   *****************************************/
  SvgInit.prototype.init = function() {

    this.panel02Svg = Snap(this.elem);

    var bg = this.panel02Svg.rect(0, 0, $(this.elem).parent().width(), $(this.elem).parent().height());

    bg.attr({
      fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'
    });
  }

  /*******************************************
   *
   *    clockwiseAnimtion
   *
   *    launch an animation(SVG)
   *    of 2 polygone clockwise animation
   *
   *****************************************/
  SvgInit.prototype.clockwiseAnimtion = function() {
    var _this = this;

    if (this.inAnim) return false;
    else this.inAnim = true;

    var pW = $(_this.elem).parent().width();
    var pH = $(_this.elem).parent().height();

    var pointsPos = [
      (pW / 2), (pH / 2), (pW / 2), 0, (pW / 2), 0, (pW / 2), 0, (pW / 2), 0, (pW / 2), 0, (pW / 2), 0
    ];


    var firstMove = pointsPos.slice();
    firstMove[4] = firstMove[6] = firstMove[8] = firstMove[10] = firstMove[12] = pW;
    var time1 = this.animTiming(pointsPos[4], firstMove[4]);

    var secondMove = firstMove.slice();
    secondMove[7] = secondMove[9] = secondMove[11] = secondMove[13] = pH;
    var time2 = this.animTiming(firstMove[7], secondMove[7]);

    var thirdMove = secondMove.slice();
    thirdMove[8] = thirdMove[10] = thirdMove[12] = 0;
    var time3 = this.animTiming(secondMove[8], thirdMove[8]);

    var fourthMove = thirdMove.slice();
    fourthMove[11] = fourthMove[13] = 0;
    var time4 = this.animTiming(thirdMove[11], fourthMove[11]);

    var fifthMove = fourthMove.slice();
    fifthMove[12] = (pW / 2);
    var time5 = this.animTiming(fourthMove[12], fifthMove[12]);



    var shape = this.panel02Svg.polygon(pointsPos).attr({
      fill: "#fff"
    });

    // Let's animate !
    shape.animate({
      points: firstMove.toString()
    }, time1, mina.linear, function() {
      this.animate({
        points: secondMove.toString()
      }, time2, mina.linear, function() {
        this.animate({
          points: thirdMove.toString()
        }, time3, mina.linear, function() {
          this.animate({
            points: fourthMove.toString()
          }, time4, mina.linear, function() {
            this.animate({
              points: fifthMove.toString()
            }, time5, mina.linear);
          });
        });
      });
    });

  }

  /*******************************************
   *
   *    animTiming
   *
   *    give the animation speed
   *    need start point(x or y)
   *    and end point(x or y)
   *
   *****************************************/
  SvgInit.prototype.animTiming = function(val1, val2) {

    if (undefined == this.perimeter) this.perimeter = ($(this.elem).parent().width() + $(this.elem).parent().height()) * 2;

    var dist = val1 > val2 ? val1 - val2 : val2 - val1;

    return Math.round(dist * this.animTime / this.perimeter);

  }


  return SvgInit;

})();


var svg = new SvgInit('#svg');

svg.clockwiseAnimtion();
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

#svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.2.0/snap.svg-min.js">
<div>
  <svg id="svg"></svg>
  <img src="http://www.rocksolidwalls.com.au/images/retaining-wall01.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

I did my test in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE(9, 11) and except IE(9, 11) it's working.

Comment: Try [raphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) I read that it handle IE bugs for SVG